# IKEv2/IPsec. Strongswan server static external ip-address. 2 pcs of Mikrotiks as clients. Routing (or what?) Mikrotiks LAN-subnets

Tags: linux, strongswan, mikrotik, ikev2

Strongswan 5.7 on Debian 10. Static "white" ip address.

2 Mikrotiks with grey ip addresses from ISPs' and NAT:

```
/ip address print
2 D 10.141.170.32/16   10.141.0.0      ether1
```

Mikrotik "A" LAN subnet: 192.168.77.0/24

Mikrotik "B" LAN subnet: 192.168.1.0/24

At this moment my IKEv2/IPsec setup is on stage below:

Tunnels is up. Mikrotiks get addresses on ether1 (WAN interface) from subnet which specified in strongswan ipsec.conf.

```
/ip address print
6 D 10.22.10.2/24      10.22.10.0      ether1
```

Mikrotiks ping each other with these addresses.

The dynamical policies generated on mikrotiks are:

```
/ip ipsec policy print  
Flags: T - template, X - disabled, D - dynamic, I - invalid, A - active, * - default 
 #     PEER                TUNNEL SRC-ADDRESS                                               DST-ADDRESS                                               PROTOCOL   ACTION  LEVEL    PH2-COUNT 
    1 T                              0.0.0.0/0                                                 0.0.0.0/0                                                 all        
 2  DA  ike2-rw-client      yes    10.22.10.2/32                                             0.0.0.0/0                                                 all        encrypt unique           1
```

How can I connect (routing or what?) Mikrotik "A" LAN with Mikrotik "B" LAN now?

Comment: Why did you assign virtual IPs to the two Mikrotiks? Why not just negotiate net-to-net policies (or do the Mikrotiks require requesting a virtual IP address)?

Comment: Yes, Mikrotik don't want to up IPsec without rightsourceip=10.22.10.0/24.

Comment: Then you have to find a way to NAT traffic from the subnets behind the Mikrotiks to the assigned virtual IP addresses so the traffic is tunneled.